# Sharepoint Online Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, sharepoint, onedrive

I have a SharePoint Online site with a Documents library and folder structure.
What i'm trying to do is, every time a user creates a folder anywhere in the site, I would like that folder not to inherit its parent folder permissions and only have permissions of the creator.

This is so I can add access to the folder later to others who might need it.

I want to do it this way because OneDrive sync needs Read access to every folder above the folders being created. So anything new would be by default restricted to the creator of the file/folder.

Is this possible? Perhaps turning off inheritance on all new folders automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow for the library, if the new item is folder, break/assign permission by REST api.

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/breakroleinheritance

/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/roleassignments/addroleassignment
```

[Sample](http://www.benprins.net/2017/01/03/sharepoint-2013-workflow-changing-permissions-with-rest-calls/)

http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-(Item-Level-Permissions)